# Using data.table package for replacing value problem

Tags: r, data.table

Im using the data.table package for replacing certain data with NA

```
data1 <- data.frame(x1 = -1:5,    # Create example data
                   x2 = -5:1,
                   x3 = -6:0)



library(data.table)
data1 <- data.table(data1)
rplc <- c("5", "6")
#replace x2 with NA for data smaller than -2
data1[x2 < c("-2"), x2 := NA]

#replace x2 data with NA for data larger than 2
data1[x2 > c("-2"), x2 := NA]
```

The problem arise with the condition set for the replacement of the value in column x2. When set with < -2, the value that was replaced is -1. When set > -2, the value replaced in x2 is -3,-4,-5 and 0,1 which shouldn't be logical but i have no way of fixing this

Tried like above, also tried with a positive value then it work as expected with <3 for x1 will turn -1,0,1,2 to NA which is logical. problem arise when i start comparing it with negative value

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're doing string-comparisons against integers?

Comment: compare `-1:5 < -2` with `-1:5 < "-2"`, do not cast to string for numeric comparisons

Answer (score 0):

Do not expect that comparing strings (that may otherwise look like normal numbers) with numbers and get the same results as numbers-with-numbers. The comparison is done lexicographically, which is not numerically.

Demonstration:

```r
-5:1 < -2
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
-5:1 < "-2"
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

When you do your comparisons using real numbers, I think they should meet your expectations.

```r
data1 <- data.table(x1 = -1:5, x2 = -5:1, x3 = -6:0)
data1[x2 < c(-2), x2 := NA]
data1
#       x1    x2    x3
#    <int> <int> <int>
# 1:    -1    NA    -6
# 2:     0    NA    -5
# 3:     1    NA    -4
# 4:     2    -2    -3
# 5:     3    -1    -2
# 6:     4     0    -1
# 7:     5     1     0
```